# How to check duplicate values in more then one rows in Angular ui-grid.

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am beginner in of AngularJS therefore I have a simple question. 
Is there any method provided or sample code in ui-grid to check the duplicate values in more then one rows in ui-grid.? 
i want to color the cell where duplicate value exist.

Answer (score 0):

There is no TRUE built-in way, however using $watch is one solution. If values in your ui-grid are bound to a variable called myGridVals, you would do something like this:

```
   $scope.$watch('myGridVals',function(newval,oldval) {
          // loop through myGridVals and see if newval matches anything
   });
```

Note that if your array holds objects you'll want to do a DEEP watch which means adding a third param to $watch(..,..,true);
You can also

Comment: I tried but it worked only when we have uploaded file to in ui-grid and updating of row with duplicate entity. But i have file with duplicate value and i want to color the duplicate values in first column of each row.

Comment: So you could do that a number of ways and it may depend on how you are loading the file and putting the data into the grid. You could add an event to the grid such that when the data loads or refreshes (you can check the documentation for the various events) you check for duplicate entries. You could preprocess the file and simply check the file for duplicate entries already in the grid or in the file itself, and mark those elements in the grid.  Or you could simply check all the grid values AFTER you've done whatever it is to get the items into the grid.